# React-Modal navigates on close

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-modal

Using `React`, `React-Router` and `React-Modal`.

Provided I have these routes:

```
ReactDOM.render((
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Router history={browserHistory}>
                <Route path="/" component={ App }>
                    <IndexRoute component={ Home } />
                    <Route path="/UnitPlants" component={ UnitPlants } />
                    <Redirect from="*" to="/" />
                </Route>
            </Router>
        </Provider>
    ), main);
```

I am opening a modal inside of the `UnitPlants` component

```
render: function () {
        return (
                <div>
                    <div className="row col-xs-12 padding-bottom-10">
                        <button className="pull-right btn btn-success"
                            onClick={this.openModal}>
                            <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Open my modal
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row col-xs-12">
                        //some table here... nothing important
                        <Modal
                            isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}
                            shouldCloseOnOverlayClick={false}
                            style={modalStyle}>
                            <UnitPlantDialog closeModal={this.closeModal}  unitPlant={this.state.unitPlant}/>
                        </Modal>
                    </div>
                </div>
        );
    }
```

My open and close look like this:

```
openModal: function () {
    this.setState({ modalIsOpen: true });
},
closeModal: function () {
    this.setState({ modalIsOpen: false });
}
```

Yet when I close my modal, it navigates to `http://localhost:3000/UnitPlants?plantName=&productType=1&createdAt=2016-06-02&expiresAt=` for some reason and I cannot seem to figure out why exactly.

How can I stop my modal from navigating to a route having `?.....` and thus not re-rendering my entire application?

Comment: Does your modal handle a form?

Comment: Yes it does, I have just figured out I didn't prevent the default when cancelling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to handle the default behaviour of the button in the modal.

```
closeModal: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.closeModal();
    }
```

the `e.preventDefault()` fixed the issue

Comment: The famous preventDefault() :)